# Efficient multi-thread friendly garbage collector for C/C++ (GPL compatible)?

Tags: linux, open-source

I am seeking an efficient free software *multi-thread compatible* garbage collector (with a GPLv3 compatible license, running primarily on Gnu/Linux). I want e.g. to have 4 to 8 threads running in parallel -e.g. some sort of tiny Lisp-, and allocating simultaneously. Allocation rate is expected to be rather high -with lots of values being temporary (but mutation rate should be lower).

[Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) is widely used, but is a bit slow (e.g. slower than the GC inside Ocaml).

Gnu [Epsilon GC](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/epsilon.git/tree/epsilongc) is also a possibility....

And [Rollendurchmesserzeitsammler](http://users.notam02.no/~kjetism/rollendurchmesserzeitsammler/) is nearly Boehm compatible but claims to be faster (or at least more real-time friendly).

[smieciuch GC](http://smieciuch.sourceforge.net/) is a precise GC, but I don't know if it multi-thread compatible (and it fails to compile with `g++-4.8` on my Debian/Sid/x86-64).

[SGCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sgcl/) is Windows specific.

[MeixnerGC](http://meixnergc.sourceforge.net/) is LGPLv3 & could be compiled for multithread applications, but don't compile on 64 bits Linux because of casts from pointers to `unsigned int` (it should use `intptr_t`); this has been fixed in its 0.4 release of april 7th, 2014.

[TinyGc](http://tinygc.sourceforge.net/) is Boehm compatible, but smaller and slower.

[Ravenbrook MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/) is precise, generational, rumored to be very efficient. However the API is quite complex. Most [allocations](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/topic/allocation.html) require a loop (which very often run only once).

I would prefer a precise generational copying GC .... Of course I can adapt to constraints provided by the GC (e.g. by providing relevant marking or forwarding routines or layout information, expliciting local pointers in C code and dealing with writing or reading barriers, etc...).

Any other hints?

---

To improve the question, I don't require an "easy-to-use" GC, but an efficient and multi-thread friendly one. The C (or C++) code will all be *generated*, so it is then reasonably easy to cope with requirements or conventions (e.g. write barriers, precise local roots on the call stack in some automatic variable, [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form), etc...) dictated by the GC (since it is just a matter of changing the C code generator to fit with these).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/396811/841108) on StackOverflow.

---

<sup>I did wrote several precise copying single threaded garbage collectors, e.g. [qish](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) & the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) runtime; but multi-threaded GCs are harder.</sup>

PS it would be for an hypothetical [MELT monitor](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/jit/2013-q4/msg00025.html) in relation with [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (so GPLv3 compatibility is essential).

Comment: Most GCs work with some constraints on how program data can be layed out in memory.  (E.g., what constitutes a pointer?  How are they found?).  You appear to want a GC with no such constraints (e.g., "conservative" collectors such as the Boehm collector).  I think this is a missing requirement. [I think Boehm would object to being categorized as "inefficient" especially given the conservative requirement.  What's your definition of "bit slow"?]

Comment: No, I can easily adapt to constraints provided by the GC.

Comment: Ok, outside of wanting a multi-thread garbage collector for C/C++, with GPL license, what other constrains you have and what exactly you don't want of it?